# Display 'Counter' results on seperate line (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to get it so that this code:

```
from collections import Counter
a = input('Votes: ')
a = a.split(',')
count = Counter(a)
print (count)
```

When I input something like this:

```
One,One,Two,Two,Three,Four,Five,Five
```

prints this:

```
One: 2
Two: 2
Three: 1
Four: 1
Five:2
```

instead of this:

```
Counter({'One': 2, 'Two': 2, 'Five': 2, 'Three': 1, 'Four': 1})
```

Comment: Do you need them ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) output:

```
for key, c in count.most_common():
    print("{}: {}".format(key, c))
```

The `most_common()` method gives you the items in sorted order, from most to least common:

If you need to order them by their 'came first' ordering in `a` (so `One` before `Two` simply because `One` was mentioned first) then sort them by their string index with `str.index()`.

```
for key, c in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda i: a.index(i[0])):
    print("{}: {}".format(key, c))
```

If you needed to order them by the ordinal interpretation of the numbers, use a dictionary translating words to digits:

```
numbers = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5} # expand as needed
for key, c in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda i: numbers[i[0].lower()]):
    print("{}: {}".format(key, c))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = 'One,One,Two,Two,Three,Four,Five,Five'.split(',')
>>> count = Counter(a)
>>> for key, c in count.most_common():
...     print("{}: {}".format(key, c))
... 
Five: 2
Two: 2
One: 2
Three: 1
Four: 1
>>> for key, c in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda i: a.index(i[0])):
...     print("{}: {}".format(key, c))
... 
One: 2
Two: 2
Three: 1
Four: 1
Five: 2
>>> numbers = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
>>> for key, c in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda i: numbers[i[0].lower()]):
...     print("{}: {}".format(key, c))
... 
One: 2
Two: 2
Three: 1
Four: 1
Five: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
a = input('Votes: ')
a = a.split(',')
count = Counter(a)

for key in sorted(set(a),key=lambda x: a.index(x)):
     print ("{}: {}".format(key,count[key]))

In [13]: for key in sorted(set(a),key=lambda x: a.index(x)):
   ....:          print ("{}: {}".format(key,count[key]))
   ....:     

One: 2
Two: 2
Three: 1
Four: 1
Five: 2
```

Make a `set` to remove the duplicates and use `sorted` with a  `lambda` to sort based on the index of the corresponding value in the `a` list which matches the `input` order

Answer (score 0):

One liner, sorted:

```
a = ['One','One','Two','Two','Three','Four','Five','Five']
counts = Counter(a)
print('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(*x) for x in sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: a.index(x[0]))))
```